# how to launch UIView subclass from UIViewController subclass in ipad

Tags: objective-c

view2 is a subclass of UIViewController. view1 is a subclass of UIView.

How do I launch view1 from view2?

I've tried

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

and

UIViewControllerhandler.hidden=YES;

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, use better naming. Ff something is a UIViewController subclass, call it myViewController or anything but myView.

To try to answer your question, we need a lot more information, such as where you are trying to do this from, how you showed the views, are you using a `UINavigationController` to handle them, etc. From your examples, it seems your view1 (a `UIView`) has a `UIViewController` subclass called `view2` that you want to dismiss to reshow the first view. Ff that's the case then `[view2.view removeFromSuperview];` will work.

I would take a look at the User Interface Guide provided by Apple for a better understanding of navigation and view Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

thanx alot its working now and i am not using UINavigationController handler ,I am working on Touch concept in scrollView which is there in my view2 .
my working code written in view2(ie:subclass of UIViewController):

(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

```
 NSSet *allTouches=[event allTouches];
switch ([allTouches count]) 
{    //for single touch
 case 1:{

            UITouch *touch [[allTouchesallObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
            switch ([touch tapCount]) 
           { case 1:// action part  
            //break;
             case 2://CODE to return from UIViewContoller to UIView

            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
             break;
           }
         }break;

   //for double touch
   case 2:
   { //action part
   }break;
}
```

}